# help understanding these iptables rules

Tags: iptables

So i have these iptables rules

```
sudo iptables -L -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.8.129         0.0.0.0/0            
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set k8s-nodes src
4    ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.21.5        0.0.0.0/0            
5    ACCEPT     all  --  10.53.5.52         0.0.0.0/0            
6    ACCEPT     all  --  13.xx.xx.xx         0.0.0.0/0           
7    ACCEPT     all  --  147.xx.xx.xx         0.0.0.0/0            
8    ACCEPT     all  --  147.xx.xx.xx/28    0.0.0.0/0            
9    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
10   ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11   ACCEPT     all  --  136.xx.xx.xx       0.0.0.0/0            
12   ACCEPT     all  --  10.67.0.13           0.0.0.0/0
```

The rules are doing what we want, however i'm confused why rule 10 isn't allowing everything... since its "accept any to any" but when checking from source IPs not listed in the other rules there is no access...  I think it has something to do with setting the INPUT chain to `drop` but i'm not sure.  Can someone explain this?
thanks

## edit 1

As requested in the comments.

```
iptables -nv -L --line-numbers
[...]
10     94M 7780M ACCEPT   all  --  lo   *    0.0.0.0/0         0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: You need `iptables -nv -L --line-numbers`

Comment: ah ok so now i see line 10 as

`10     94M 7780M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`

so i guess thats just allowing anything to the loopback?

Answer (score 0):

If you run just `iptables -n -L` then you do not get all the relevant information.

`iptables -nv -L` shows the amount of packets which were matched by the rule (which would show that a certain rule matches everything as all rules after that would have a counter of zero) and additional conditions like input or output interface, port numbers and so on.

In your case the seeming catch-all rule is limited to local traffic. This is a typical configuration.